# How to set the state of DropdownMenuItem when I got a snapshot from the item property of DropdownButton widget in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to get the **document id of each firebase document** in a `DropdownMenuItem` and I succesfully manage to do that by moving the query outside my widget and initialize the stream in a initState but I struggle in how to `setState` when the user **select a different choice**, when I got the id from the `DropdownButton` item property.

```
class BoxDestination extends StatefulWidget {
      const BoxDestination({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<BoxDestination> createState() => _BoxDestinationState();
    }
    
    class _BoxDestinationState extends State<BoxDestination> {
    
      Stream<QuerySnapshot>? _governorates;
      @override
      void initState() {
        _governorates= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Gouvernorat").snapshots();
        return super.initState();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return   Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _governorates,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot) {
                  return DropdownButton(
                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                    hint: const Text("Governorate"),
                    // Array list of items
                    items: snapshot.data?.docs.map((govData) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: govData.id,//variable
                        child: Text(govData.id),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    // After selecting the desired option,it will
                    // change button value to selected value
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        //I cannot do this because govData is Undefined.
                        govData.id=value;
                      },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one different variable in order to store the selected value.
Because on every setstate stream builder will rebuild and it will loose it's old state.

Maybe you could do like this.

```
class _BoxDestinationState extends State<BoxDestination> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot>? _governorates;
  dynamic selectedValue;

   @override
   void initState() {
     _governorates =
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Gouvernorat").snapshots();
       return super.initState();
    }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _governorates,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return DropdownButton(
 // Down Arrow Icon
            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
            hint: const Text("Governorate"),
  // Array list of items
            items: snapshot.data?.docs.map((govData) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: govData.id, //variable
                child: Text(govData.id),
              );
            }).toList(),
 // After selecting the desired option,it will
 // change button value to selected value
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(
                () {
  //remove govData.
                  selectedValue = value;
                },
              );
            },

            // use value to select a different choice
            value: selectedValue.id,
          );
        }),
  ],
);
```

}
}

Comment: value: selectedValue.id,
can't be assigned outside the DropdownMenuItem it give me this error: 
The named parameter 'value' isn't defined

Comment: To store the selected value I could move selectedValue outside the widget build method, but this is my problem because I don't know how could I assign govData.id which i got from the snapshot item to a variable outside DropdownButton

Comment: Why do you want to assign govData.id? it's not a value when you are mapping it to the items.

refer to this you would get the idea. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-dropdownbutton-widget/

Answer (score 0):

After following [this](https://geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-dropdownbutton-widget) and with the guide of @kishan busa it turns out that we should have a null value first then assign a new value to it in the `setState()`

```
class BoxDestination extends StatefulWidget {
      const BoxDestination({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<BoxDestination> createState() => _BoxDestinationState();
    }
    
    class _BoxDestinationState extends State<BoxDestination> {
      String? Governorate;
      Stream<QuerySnapshot>? _governorates;
      @override
      void initState() {
        _governorates= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Gouvernorat").snapshots();
        return super.initState();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return   Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _governorates,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot) {
                  return DropdownButton(
            value: Governorate,
                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                    hint: const Text("Governorate"),
                    // Array list of items
                    items: snapshot.data?.docs.map((govData) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: govData.id,
                        child: Text(govData.id),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        Governorate=value!;
                      },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```